# Autoresize of UIWebView to fit content

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, resize

I'm actually developing an iOS App that have to display an HTML code downloaded from a server.

My view is composed of a Grouped TableView, with one cell per section and the cell is just composed by an UIWebView which has to display the HTML code.

I don't want the UIWebView to be scrollable up/down, I just want to allow right/left scrolling, I want it to be set to the height of its content.

I read a lot of topics about this problem but any solution is fully functional for me.

What is strange according to me is that for some cells I get the right height and it's correctly set but not from every cells ...

This is the code I tried (with several tests still written) :

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false

    let size = self.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(self.frame.width, CGFloat(FLT_MAX)))
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, size.height);

    let test1 = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.offsetHeight;")
    let test2 = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.scrollHeight;")
    let test3 =  webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")

    let height = CGFloat(Double(test2!)!)

    if(self.containingVC is InfoDrugViewController){
        let VC = self.containingVC as! InfoDrugViewController
        VC.heightReady(height, index: self.index.section)
    }else{ if (self.containingVC is InfoProtocolViewController){
        let VC = self.containingVC as! InfoProtocolViewController
        VC.heightReady(height, index: self.index.section)
        }
    }

}
```

If someone knows how to managed to always get the right height, It'll be perfect !

(Note that the HTML code is downloaded from a server and was generated by a WYSIWYG (CKEditor) textfield from a website.)

Answer (score 0):

It find a working solution, maybe it's no the cleanest one, but at least it works :

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
    var frame = self.frame
    frame.size.width = self.containingVC.view.frame.size.width
    frame.size.height = 1
    self.frame = frame
    frame.size.height = self.scrollView.contentSize.height
    self.frame = frame

    let test0 = self.scrollView.contentSize.height

    let size = self.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(self.frame.width, CGFloat(FLT_MAX)))
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, size.height);

    let test1 = CGFloat(Double(webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.offsetHeight;")!)!)
    let test2 = CGFloat(Double(webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.scrollHeight;")!)!)
    let test3 = CGFloat(Double(webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.clientHeight")!)!)
    let test4 = CGFloat(Double(webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")!)!)
    let test5 = CGFloat(Double(webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.documentElement.clientHeight")!)!)
    let test6 = CGFloat(Double(webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.documentElement.offsetHeight")!)!)

    print("0: \(test0) | 1: \(test1) | 2: \(test2) | 3: \(test3) | 4: \(test4) | 5: \(test5) | 6: \(test6)")


    let height = max(test0, test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6)

    if(self.containingVC is InfoDrugViewController){
        let VC = self.containingVC as! InfoDrugViewController
        VC.heightReady(height, index: self.index.section)
    }else{ if (self.containingVC is InfoProtocolViewController){
        let VC = self.containingVC as! InfoProtocolViewController
        VC.heightReady(height, index: self.index.section)
        }
    }
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true

}
```